# Django - Stripe subscription

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have a view that uses Stripe to charge an amount and then redirect the user to a subscription page, but how can I prevent a user from accessing the url directly?

Charge view :

```
def testview(request):

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=2000,
        currency="usd",
        source="tok_visa", # obtained with Stripe.js
        description="Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com"
    )

    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

My subscription creation view:

```
def create_sub(request):
     plan1 = "plan_DiiAhydC7AxqeG"
     plan2 = "plan_DiiAypModfV7VJ"

     plan = request.GET.get('plan')

    if plan == '1':
        active_plan = plan1
    elif plan == '2':
        active_plan = plan2

    sub = stripe.Subscription.create(
        customer=request.user.stripe_id,
        items=[
            {
                "plan": active_plan,
            },
        ]
   )
```

My html charge template:

```
<form action="/test/create-sub?plan=2" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
 <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="stripe_api_code"
    data-amount="100000"
    data-name="Bilpard"
    data-description="Paid plan"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
 </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Did the answer below helped you to solve your issue? If not, comment on that in order to improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping the `testview` view inside the [require_post](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) decorator?

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST()
def testview(request):

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=2000,
        currency="usd",
        source="tok_visa", # obtained with Stripe.js
        description="Charge for jenny.rosen@example.com"
    )

    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

With that, only POST requests allowed to access this view.